# (Oneliner) append returned list into different lists

Tags: python, list, variables, return

im looking for a oneliner (if possible) to return three values of a function and append them to three different lists directly after (here a, b, c).

My printout is "1 3 9" right now as my variables get repurposed in the loop.
Im looking for following printout:
[1, 1, 1] [3, 3, 3] [9, 9, 9]

Do you have an idea?
Otherwise im going for a three- or four-liner. Id like to challenge pythons semantic though. ;)

```
def return_values_list():
"""Simple function to test how returns work."""
    return [1, 3, 9]

a, b, c = [], [], []

for n in range(3):
    a, b, c = return_values_list()

print (a, b, c)
```

Comment: Why one-liner as condition? Read zen of python. SO is not code golf site

Comment: @buran
I would like to explore the extend python comprehends abstract concepts of line of codes and I also want to reduce repeated lines or wasteful usage of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to work with `zip`, e.g.,

```py
>>> list(zip(*(return_values_list() for _ in range(3))))
[(1, 1, 1), (3, 3, 3), (9, 9, 9)]
```

or, if you want to assign to `a`, `b`, `c`,

```py
>>> a, b, c = zip(*(return_values_list() for _ in range(3)))
>>> a
(1, 1, 1)
>>> b
(3, 3, 3)
>>> c
(9, 9, 9)
```

which is of course equivalent to

```py
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> a, b, c = zip(*repeat(return_values_list(), 3))
```

but it wasn't clear if imports are allowed.

Comment: Provided the lists are initially empty and only built in this loop, this is the way to go.

Comment: What if i want to add more values from a permanent stream of data?
I want to evaluate an api call (api call returns a json). There return three values (inner function) from one dict and append them to three different lists (outer function). The list is accumulated then and used in a graphic evaluation.

Comment: @404rorre not sure if I'm following, but note that `zip(*(return_values_list() for _ in range(3)))` is equivalent to `zip(return_values_list(), return_values_list(), return_values_list())` so you can substitute the function calls with something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as a solution

```
a=[1,2,3]
c=np.repeat(a,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `zip` function along with a list comprehension can achieve this:

```
def return_values_list():
    """Simple function to test how returns work."""
    return [1, 3, 9]

a, b, c = [], [], []

for n in range(3):
    [data.append(value) for data, value in zip([a, b, c], return_values_list())]

print (a, b, c)
```

To even make the loop part of the one-liner:

```
def return_values_list():
    """Simple function to test how returns work."""
    return [1, 3, 9]

a, b, c = [], [], []

[data.append(value) for data, value in zip([a, b, c], return_values_list()) for _ in range(3)]

print (a, b, c)
```

Comment: Please don't use list-comps for side effects; better use a regular loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
a, b, c = np.split(np.repeat(return_values_list(), 3), 3)
```

Output:

```
(array([1, 1, 1]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([9, 9, 9]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a list of lists then unpack them into your variables

```
a, b, c = [[e]*3 for e in (1, 3, 9)]

print(a, b, c)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 1, 1] [3, 3, 3] [9, 9, 9]
```